# jq-idealforms Send Form Via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a simple login form.

```
<form id="login" action="process/login_process.php" method="POST" name="login" accept-charset="utf-8">
<div><label>Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" data-ideal="required"/></div>
<div><label>Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" data-ideal="required"/></div>
<div><button id="submit" type="submit">Login</button></div>
</form>
```

I'm using JQ-IDEALFORMS for the validation and overall prettiness of the form. I'm having the hardest time figuring out how to submit the form via ajax. This is the javascript I have so far:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/jquery.idealforms.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var options = {
        onSuccess: function() {
            $.post('process/login_process.php', $myform.serialize())
            alert(responseXML);
        }
    };
    var $myform = $('#login').idealforms(options).data('idealforms');
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        $.post('process/login_process.php', $myform.serialize());
        alert('hello');
    });
```

I followed the very limited directions in their documentation and added the $.post to the onSuccess action in the options variable. That doesn't work. I then tried to add a listener to the submit button and the alert box never comes up, meaning that listener is never triggering. How should this be done? I've been able to submit the form, but when I do, it redirects the page to my php page where my XML is being echo'd. For some reason, I can't get it to echo back to my login page.

Comment: If I remove the action, nothing at all happens when I hit the submit button. Added the action successfully sends the information to the php page, but not via ajax, it redirects the browser to that php page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the action attribute of the form, you have to return false to prevent form to be submitted or change the action to `javascript:void(0)`...

```
<form id="login" action="javascript:submitForm()" method="POST" name="login" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

And in the JS

```
var submitForm = function() {
    var options = {
       onSuccess: function() {
          $.post('process/login_process.php', $myform.serialize())
          alert(responseXML);
       }
    };
    var $myform = $('#login').idealforms(options).data('idealforms');
     //not sure this part is needed because Post already call in the success method of idealforms
    $.post('process/login_process.php', $myform.serialize());
    alert('hello');
};
```

Comment: This prevented the page from redirecting to my php page, but now when I hit the submit button, nothing at all happens.

Comment: Normally the `$('#submit').click(function() {
        $.post('process/login_process.php', $myform.serialize());
        alert('hello');
    });` will do the trick... I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Send form through ajax.

```
var createForm = $("form#login");
var postData = createForm.serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Offers/CreateOffer",
            data: postData,
            success: function (result, textStatus, jqXhr) {
           }
         });
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining the parameters in the success fuction: function (result, textStatus, jqXhr)

Comment: use alert in sucess portion for result which shows all the things like usename and password fields are serialize `alert(result);`